# Debugging a dylib in Xcode that was built without debug symbols

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv, xcode5, dylib

I am building a C++ application in Xcode 5 that links to external dynamic libraries (OpenCV 2.4.6, installed via macports). These dynamic libraries appear to have been compiled without debugging symbols, since, when I hit an error in them, I can't see the source code; all I see is assembly code.

I have separately downloaded the OpenCV source code from the OpenCV web site. Is there a way for me to tell Xcode where to look for the source files for the dylibs so that I can step through the OpenCV code in the Xcode debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. When a library is compiled with debugging support, additional data is bundled into the shared library which contains a mapping along the lines of "address 0x00240008 corresponds to main.c:24", "address 0x0024001a corresponds to main.c:25", etc. If the modules were built without debugging support, the files are now simply binary blobs that contain machine code and the debugger has no way to translate the machine language back into the source code.

However, since you have the source code, you can recompile the library to include that information and install your custom version. For OpenCV, this will be a command like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:=Debug .
```

Comment: Thanks, Ryan, that seems to have done the trick. I used your cmake variable but with the syntax in the [OpenCV Linux installation instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#building-opencv-from-source-using-cmake-using-the-command-line) and I can now step into the OpenCV code when debugging. Compiling the source was way easier than I was expecting!